# jQuery activate function when TD gets focus

Tags: jquery, html-table, tabindex, tablecell

I've made an editable table that works well when my user clicks a table cell. However, I need the same functionality when the user tabs to a table cell (no mouse click). Here's the relevant jQuery:

```
$('.cd_editable').on('click', 'td', function () { 
    //do stuff
});
```

This works great when the user clicks a table cell. Is there some way I can alter this line so that it fires when my user tabs there? All the editable TDs have tabindex numbers, so the tabbing is working.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: so use focus event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the focus event.

```js
$("table tbody").on("focus", "td", function () {
  console.log(this)
})
```

```css
td {
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}

td:focus {
  background-color: #CCC
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td contenteditable="true"></td>
      <td contenteditable="true"></td>
      <td contenteditable="true"></td>
      <td contenteditable="true"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td contenteditable="true"></td>
      <td contenteditable="true"></td>
      <td contenteditable="true"></td>
      <td contenteditable="true"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```